# How do I filter based on a LAG() result in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a collection on my apex page. I am trying to build an HTML table with the result. The problem is some of the cells are not being printed into the table. I have a feeling it is due to problematic filtering in the where clause.

```
BEGIN

FOR record IN (select c001, c002, case
     when lag(c004,1) over (order by c003, c005) is null then '<tr><td>'||'<img src="#APP_IMAGES#Images/bluelabel-40-'||c004||'.jpg">'||'</td>' 
     when lag(c004,1) over (order by c003, c005) = c004 then ''
     else '</tr><tr><td>'||'<img src="#APP_IMAGES#Images/bluelabel-40'||c004||'.jpg">'||'</td>' 
   end html_header,
    case
     when lag(c006,1) over (order by c003, c005) is null then '<td class="Border" valign="top"><ul>'||decode(c009,null,'&nbsp', '<li><a target="_blank" class="'||c011||'" href="'||c012||'"><h2>'||c009||'</h2><p>'||c010||'</p></a></li>') -- first row
     when lag(c006,1) over (order by c003, c005) = c006 then decode(c009,null,'&nbsp', '<li><a target="_blank" class="'||c011||'" href="'||c012||'"><h2>'||c009||'</h2><p>'||c010||'</p></a></li>') 
     else '</ul></td><td class="Border" valign="top"><ul>'||decode(c009,null,'&nbsp', '<li><a target=_blank class="'||c011||'" href="'||c012||'"><h2>'||c009||'</h2><p>'||c010||'</p></a></li>') 
   end html_table
   from apex_collections
   where collection_name = 'COLL_IMKN' and (c001 like :P5_TEAM or c002 like :P5_TEAM or (c001 is null and c002 is null))
   order by c003, c005
          )
LOOP
htp.p(record.html_header || record.html_table
);
END LOOP;
htp.p('
  </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
');
END;
```

Note: the values are correct, what I am trying to do is to get the `where` to specify `when lag(c006,1) over (order by c003, c005) is null`

Desired Output
[image: Desired output]

Actual Output
[image: Desired output]
NOTE: please disregard the difference in cells, had a new row added to the database.

The table should provide a 3x3 table with three labels on the left of the table

Comment: Please edit the question and share the actual and expected output.

Comment: You don't.  You use a CTE or subquery to define a column alias for `lag()` and then use that in the outer query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried to apply `html_table = '</ul></td><td class="Border" valign="top"><ul>&nbsp'` and received the error `ORA-06550: line 46, column 133: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "HTML_TABLE": invalid identifier`

Comment: @Tejash I added comparative images, it should be noted that the `MEDIUM` row is missing completely. The desired output is the same query just not using a collection to specify the data. I have checked on a report to compare the script and it is present in the report...

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `LAG()` in the `WHERE` clause you'll need to rephrase your `SELECT` query to produce the column with the "lag" value.

If the [wrong] query you want takes the form:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where lag(col1) = 123 -- wrong: LAG() won't work
```

Then you must rephrase it as:

```
select col1, col2
from (
  select col1, col2, lag(col1) as prev_col1
  from t
) x
where prev_col1 = 123 -- works!
```